# Get data from url restricted by security token

Tags: json, angularjs, security

I have a url like https://xyz-xyz-xyz.com/GetLatestAnnouncements

```
{
    "Count" : "50",
    "ProfileID" : "123",
    "SecurityToken": "a1adf45141df15e45s1df5"
}
```

How can I get JSON from this url using security token and profileID in AngularJS.

Comment: Is that JSON the exact format of input that the url endpoint expects?

Comment: I have just ProfileID, SecurityToken and URL, I am newly in angularJS. Can you write full script of angularJS code to get JSON

Comment: You have to pass some data to the endpoint - do you know exactly what it is expecting? Does it expect the token in request Body or in http header? Does it expect the ProfileID and know what to do with it? These things are unclear from your question. I could show you how to do a generic POST with the data you show, but that doesn't mean it will necessarily work.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying Ajax(with jQuery) then:

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url: "https://xyz-xyz-xyz.com/GetLatestAnnouncements",
  success: function(data){
    var json_data = JSON.parse(data);
  }
});
```

Hope the URL endpoint returns data in json format.

Comment: I have just ProfileID, SecurityToken and URL, I am newly in angularJS. Can you write full script of angularJS code to get JSON

Comment: Also check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_customers_json) if it helps